# Making a list of TextBoxes

Tags: c#, arraylist

**Code:-**

```
public partial class Players : Form
{
    public TextBox[] spelers = new TextBox[7];
    List<string> spelersSpel = new List<string>();
    public Form1 game = new Form1();
    public Players()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        spelers[0] = inputSpeler1;
        spelers[1] = inputSpeler2;
        spelers[2] = inputSpeler3;
        spelers[3] = inputSpeler4;
        spelers[4] = inputSpeler5;
        spelers[5] = inputSpeler6;
    }

    private void btnSpelers_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < spelers.Length; i++)
        {
            if (spelers[i] != null)
                spelersSpel.Add(spelers[i].Text);

        }

        foreach (TextBox item in spelers)
        {
            if (item != null)
                spelersSpel.Add(item.Text);
        }
        MessageBox.Show(spelersSpel.Count.ToString());
        game.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

I've got 6 textboxes that I've put into an array. Then I want to put this array into a form. Because I don't know how much input I get from the textboxes I don't use an array. But when I want to see how big my list is. It's saying 6. If I only type text in the first textbox the list should be 1.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why use an array?  Just make a list and iterate over it with a foreach loop or LINQ statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the input count by this way：

```
spelersSpel.Clear();
foreach (TextBox item in spelers)
{
    if (item != null && item.Text.Trim() != "") //check if null or empty
    spelersSpel.Add(item.Text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing the TextBox object with its Text property.
If I understand correctly you want the `List<string>` to contain only the text for the textboxes that are not empty, so your code should be something like this

```
    spelersSpel.Clear();
    foreach (TextBox item in spelers)
    {
        if (item != null && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item.Text))
            spelersSpel.Add(item.Text);
    }
```

Notice that you declare the array to contain 7 TextBoxes (index from 0 to 6) but you add only 6 textboxes to it, so you need always this check for NULL because, when you loop over your elements, you have a NULL entry in your array at index 6. So, perhaps, if you have only 6 textboxes it is better to declare the array with

```
 public TextBox[] spelers = new TextBox[6];
```

Next, in the click event, you execute two loops to fill the list, this of course will duplicate the list content.

However, I think that a better approach is to use directly a `List<TextBox>`, work with it and get rid of the array and the `List<string>`

```
public partial class Players : Form
{
    public List<TextBox> spelers;
    public Form1 game = new Form1();

    public Players()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        spelers = new List<TextBox>()
        { 
           inputSpeler1, inputSpeler2, inputSpeler3,
           inputSpeler4, inputSpeler5, inputSpeler6
        }
    }

    private void btnSpelers_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(spelers
                  .Count(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.Text))
                  .ToString());
        game.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because (spelers[i] != null) and (item != null) does not check whether the textboxes are blank; It means the array element is null or not.

If you want to check whether your textbox is blank, you should find property Text;

```
if (item.Text != "")
```

I'm not able to use my IDE and it is not sure, but try this.

```
public partial class Players : Form
{
    public TextBox[] spelers = new TextBox[6]; // [7];
    List<string> spelersSpel = new List<string>();
    public Form1 game = new Form1();
    public Players()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        spelers[0] = inputSpeler1;
        spelers[1] = inputSpeler2;
        spelers[2] = inputSpeler3;
        spelers[3] = inputSpeler4;
        spelers[4] = inputSpeler5;
        spelers[5] = inputSpeler6;
    }
    private void btnSpelers_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        /*
        // 1.
        for (int i = 0; i < spelers.Length; i++)
        {
            if (spelers[i] != null) {
                throw new Exception("NullTextBoxException");
            }
            else if (spelers[i].Text == "") {
                // skip when the textbox is empty
                continue;
            }
            spelersSpel.Add(spelers[i].Text);
        }
        */

        foreach (TextBox item in spelers)
        {
            if (item != null) {
                // throw exception when referring textbox is null
                throw new Exception("NullTextBoxException");
            }
            else if (item.Text == "") {
                // skip when the textbox is empty
                continue;
            }
            spelersSpel.Add(item.Text);
        }

        MessageBox.Show(spelersSpel.Count.ToString());
        game.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```